# How I write data in span when i am using jQuery EasyUI

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery-easyui

I am using `AJAX` for data communication from server but in case of success i want to write the data into `span(id=cartcount)` but it's not worked please help how i achieve this concept

```
function addToCart(pid, name) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure to add "+name + " to cart?")) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  'addcart',
                    data: {
                        pid: pid
                    },
                    success: function(obj) {                         
                      $('#cartcount').val(obj);                         
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
   $('#cartcount').html(obj);
```

or

```
$('#cartcount').text(obj);
```

Comment: I see  $('#cartcount').val(obj);

Comment: Right @dllhell but before use of val  i used html to write data in to span.

Comment: write console.log(obj); to be sure you have something in this obj

Comment: ya in success case i check the data by using alert(obj);

Comment: thank you dear for discussion it's my fault in writing id of span so your code is work .